# is there any way to reach working objects on RAM in java

Tags: java, object, runtime, ram, jdialog

I want to know is there a way to reach working objects in RAM in Java..
let's think that I have a JDialog class which is not modal . and dialog is appears in action of list compaund with given parameters [non modal dialogs running statistically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuAwJ.png)

so that as u see in pic every time new dialog is appears .
 Is there any way to se if the dialog with given parameters is running (still not disposed ) without collecting opened dialogs in to some array or collection ..
is there any way to search for them in RAM or JVM memory ?

Comment: Why not just use a modal JDialog?

Comment: it's easy to compare the models ..for this prog .. but it's just an example .. sometimes you just  lost the way of sending objects from pattern to another .. maybe with it you can send them to the stack or runtime and extract from another pattern (Ex :component) ..

Comment: store them in a list?!

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a few of the absolute basic tutorials if you're wondering how you can search the RAM for "lost" objects..

Comment: I want to make  if (the dialog with this parameters is on screen or still not  disposed ) make it front and dont open another ..

Comment: Thanks for ur help ..but that what i mentioned about "whitout storing them in list or any collection"

Comment: store them in a list, on click check if it's already opened, if yes => foreground. I think you should read some more tutorials on objective-orientation.

Comment: why do you not want to store them?!

Comment: Right, but why would you ever choose the way you are asking about over storing it in a tried and true Java data structure?

Comment: storing them in a list/collection does not take significantly more RAM if you're affraid of that.

Comment: I think there is no any problems with tourtoils ..
Im storing them in a list now but there is a problem appears and amazingly not every time :).. what is happening whith the dialog object in list after you dispose it from inside .. ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know is there a way to reach working objects in RAM in Java

Yes. All object are "in the RAM"

> Is there any way to se if the dialog with given parameters is running

Store them in a list, that way you can access them.

Comment: for that reason I've mentioned "without storing them in a list or any collection "..
so it means there is not any way of doing this :(
Thanks for ur help..

Comment: but WHY?! please tell us why you do not want to store them.

Comment: I think there is no any problems with tourtoils .. Im storing them in a list now but there is a problem appears and amazingly not every time :).. what is happening whith the dialog object in list after you dispose it from inside .. ?
 :)